# Modify script from another script

Tags: matlab

I have a script that is run inside a loop (some constants are modified at each iteration). Is there a way to comment out a line of the script without modifying the .m file?

**UPDATE:**
Following the answer from Floris and Matthew Simoneau, I made a function trying to do the same thing (and it works). The skipLineParameter is a string referencing to a base workspace variable that has a value of 0 (don't skipline) or 1 (skipline) :

```
function skipline(skipLineParameter, parameter, default)
    try
        a = evalin('base', skipLineParameter);
        if ~a
            assignin('base', parameter, default);
        end
    catch
        assignin('base', parameter, default);
    end
end
```

Comment: You could add an `if` statement... the line will only run if the condition is true. But that seems to easy as an answer? If you need, you can set a variable `skipLine3` in the main loop when you want line 3 in the script skipped, with line 3 starting `if ~skipLine3, <some code>; end`

Comment: Might be better to post what you want to achieve with this or the origin of your question because right now I can't imagine a situation where this would make any sense.

Comment: "Commenting out a line" is by definition modifying the file.  I think you want to skip that line under certain circumstances, which could be done by a conditional.

Comment: @Floris, the fact is that the script that defines the constant can also be used outside the loop (so it would be looking for a skipline parameter that doesn't exist.

Comment: @M456 Indeed, i want to skip a specific line.

Comment: @Layne, the loop is running a simulink model. The constants are declared to the workspace before running the model. The model is called inside a loop for doing Monte Carlo runs (hence, some parameters need to be modified, and some others not).

Comment: I like the solution you came up with. It is clean, and preserves variables in their proper namespace. Presumably, your configuration script becomes a series of lines of the form `skipline('skipLine3', B, 4);` . Might be worth writing (and later, accepting) your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).  Here's how to turn runSub into a function:

```
function runSub(ii,skip)
A = 1;
B = 2;
if ~skip, B=B*2; end
fprintf(1, 'for iteration %d B is %d\n', ii, B);
```

You can access it in the loop like this:

```
for ii = 1:9
    skipLine3 = (mod(ii,3)==0);
    runSub(ii,skipLine3)
end
```

Comment: I would have suggested using a function if he didn't specifically ask for a "script". There is no "right" answer to this question - your solution is more robust, but further from what was asked... And if the script ends up setting parameters that are needed at the main level, a function doesn't work (unless you start adding globals, returning multiple variables, etc). This is one of many places where Matlab allows one to do things that contravene good coding practices.

Comment: I've put an update in my post, let me know what you guys think of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible approach - using a condition that is set in the main program to decide whether to execute a particular line in the script.

If your main program is

```
for ii = 1:9
  skipLine3 = (mod(ii,3)==0);
  runSub
end
```

And `runSub.m` looks like this:

```
A = 1;
B = 2;
% modified lines to trap condition where 'skipLine3' doesn't exist:
if ~exist('skipLine3', 'var') skipMe = false; else skipMe = skipLine3; end
if ~skipMe, B=B*2; end
fprintf(1, "for iteration %d B is %d\n", ii, B)
```

Then the output will be:

```
for iteration 1 B is 4
for iteration 2 B is 4
for iteration 3 B is 2
for iteration 4 B is 4
for iteration 5 B is 4
for iteration 6 B is 2
for iteration 7 B is 4
for iteration 8 B is 4
for iteration 9 B is 2
```

As you can see - the `skipLine3` parameter, which is set in the main loop (every third iteration), affects whether line 3 (`B=B*2`) is executed in the script.

Comment: After taking a look at your code, i think that would be the easiest way to do it. I just didn't want to modify the equivalent of your `runSub.m` file (hence why i wanted to do it outside the script).

Comment: I have modified the code to deal with the situation where your script is run when `skipLine3` isn't defined...